# Can I reference or reuse a Python function parameter for other function parameters?

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing

I'm creating a function taking one or two shape-lists `A = [x1,y1,c1]` / `B = [x2,y2,c2]` as input. If both shapes A and B are provided, each is used in one respective place A and B. If only one shape (A) is provided, by default the function implicitly uses it on both different places.

I solved this with an if-else construct:

```
def data_process(shape_A, shape_B = None):
  # ... some code ...
  res1 = process.shape(shape_A)    # shape A is always used
  if shape_B is not None:
      res2 = process.shape(shape_B)
  else: 
      res2 = process.shape(shape_A)
  return res1, res2

data_process(my_shape_A)  # call 1
data_process(my_shape_A, shape_B=my_shape_B)  # call 2
```

However I thought something much more elegant would be referencing shape_A as default in the function definition with **`shape_B = shape_A`**:

```
def data_process(shape_A, shape_B = shape_A):
  # ... some code ...
  res1 = process.shape(shape_A)    # shape_A is always used
  res2 = process.shape(shape_B)    # if shape_B not provided, shape_B = shape_A
  return res1, res2
```

Since simply doing it gives me the error that I'm referencing unknown variables, I was wondering: **Is there a way to reference or reuse a Python function parameter for other function parameters** (of the same function)?

This is just one straightforward use-case, but I think defaulting function parameters based on other function parameters would be quite useful to save a few lines of code.

Comment: `shape_A` in your function header is nothing more than a name of a positional parameter. Your use of the `if-else` and `None` is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. But whats wrong with

```
def data_process(shape_A, shape_B = None):
    if shape_B is None:
        shape_B = shape_A
    # rest of function not worrying about whether shape_B was passed or not
```

?

Comment: Thanks, "No, there isn't" answers my question, so I'll accept this. Like you and others point out, I guess there isn't something wrong with these versions - I just would've liked **all the "default value" logic in one place** - as opposed to: `def fn(`some default values`): '''`... a long fn doc...`''' `some more default values and potentially a lot of init code`rest of the function`. I am surprised that even though apparently there is no such thing noone appreciates the beauty of what I had in mind ;]

Comment: The reason is because of the way python works. `def f(x=a): pass` evaluates `a` when the function is **defined**, not when it is **called**. So `a = 3; def f(x = a): pass` is the same as `def f(x = 3)` which is useful. Your suggestion would make `a = 3; def f(a, b=a): pass` ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see anything wrong with your current code from a logic or efficiency perspective. There are some alternatives you can consider *for aesthetic reasons only*.

This assumes that a shape, if provided, is a tuple.

```
def data_process2(shape_A, shape_B=None):
    res1 = process.shape(shape_A)
    res2 = process.shape(shape_B if shape_B else shape_A)
    return res1, res2

def data_process3(shape_A, shape_B=None):
    if shape_B:
        shape_B = shape_A
    res1 = process.shape(shape_A)
    res2 = process.shape(shape_B)
    return res1, res2
```

Comment: This is bad advice. Passing `shape_B = 0` is not the same as passing `shape_B = None` but both cause `shape_B == shape_A` in this code. Instead use `shape_B if shape_B is not None else shape_A`.

Comment: @FHTMitchell, I disagree. A shape, if provided, should be a tuple, and `(0, 0, 0)`, for example, is considered `True`. If user wants to make his code fully fool-proof, he should apply type checks or `try / except` (make sure there are no integers, or even strings!). To illustrate, try `x = np.empty((0)); bool(x.shape)`.

Comment: `x = np.arange(5); x.shape = 5; print(x)` is valid numpy. More importantly `y = np.array([]); y.shape = 0; print(y)` also works. Your demonstration of `x = np.empty((0))` is another good example, because `(0) != (0,)`.

Comment: Your example proves my point! When you set a shape to an integer, it's stored as a tuple.. `x = np.arange(5); x.shape = 5; isinstance(x.shape, tuple)`. Even for your empty array case..

Comment: Right, so passing integer shapes to numpy is valid python. Who cares how they are stored? The point is that the function above (`process.shape`) may well be doing what I was doing and what's the point in restricting that?

Comment: Shapes are not integers. They never are. They can't be. You can use an integer to set a shape, but shapes are tuples.. Read the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html) if you are still not sure.

Comment: I don't disagree with that, I have always known that. But maybe the `process.shape` function is defined as `def shape(self, shape): self.array.shape = shape` in which case `process.shape(0)` should set the shape to `0`, **not** set the shape to `shape_A`. If you are going to restrict to only tuples then you must have an `isinstance` check, otherwise this is in fact a silent error!.